# Additional consequence of Urysohn's Lemma?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, separation-axioms

Urysohn's Lemma states that for any normal topological space $X$ and closed disjoint subsets $A,B\subset X$, we can find a continuous function $f\colon X\to[0,1]$ such that $f|_{A}=0$ and $f|_{B}=1$. But can we always find $f$ such that $f>0$ on $X\setminus A$? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you want, is a *perfectly* normal space.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks for your reply! Could you elaborate on that? And does compactness imply perfectly normal?

Comment: For an explicit example, take the Alexandroff double circle.

Comment: @Calculix No. Even Hausdorff compact is not enough. The Tychonoff plank is a counterexample

Comment: As Hagen said, you want a perfectly normal space. A space $X$ is perfectly normal iff whenever $H$ and $K$ are disjoint closed sets in $X$, there is a continuous $f:X\to[0,1]$ such that $H=f^{-1}[\{0\}$ and $K=f^{-1}[\{1\}]$, precisely the condition that you want. This is equivalent to requiring that $X$ be normal and have the property that every closed set is a $G_\delta$ set, i.e., the intersection of countably many open sets.